# How to make this SELECT Query in UPDATE Query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT accounts.id, accounts.email FROM accounts
INNER JOIN (SELECT email FROM accounts
GROUP BY email HAVING count(id) > 5) dup ON accounts.email = dup.email
```

How to `UPDATE` only results of this query?

Comment: What do you want to update?

Comment: UPDATE accounts SET accounts.active=0

Comment: have a look to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE accounts
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT email FROM accounts
  GROUP BY email HAVING count(id) > 5) dup 
ON accounts.email = dup.email
SET active = 0
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1533/1

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with a subquery as follow

```
UPDATE account a
SET a.active = 0
WHERE a.id IN 
(
    SELECT accounts.id
    FROM accounts
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT email 
        FROM accounts
        GROUP BY email 
        HAVING count(id) > 5
    ) dup 
    ON accounts.email = dup.email
)
```

Comment: @NeT32 if my answer solved your question you might consider to accept it ao you will also help people in the future with similar problems

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
UPDATE accounts SET active='0' WHERE id IN ((SELECT accounts.id FROM accounts) AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT email FROM accounts
GROUP BY email HAVING count(id) > 5) dup ON a.accounts.email = dup.email)
```

Comment: yes, but i receive this error: "You can`t specify target table 'accounts' for updade in FROM clause".

Comment: @NeT32 try it like this, this creates an implicit temporary table so it isn't counted as the same table. But this is a workaround that has low performance... So just use it if you absolutely need it.